# Ansible: Global template folder?

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

*Couldn't find anything google'ing.*

There is *group_vars/all/* for variables. Is there something similar for templates? I would like to use some templates across multiple roles.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can put your global templates into `templates` directory at the top level of Ansible layout (same level as `group_vars`). BTW same goes for global files.

```
files/
group_vars/
roles/
site.yml
templates/
```

Answer (score 6):

It was possible before 2.2.1, but not after. See issue [20442](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20442).

There's a patch that allows you to do out-of-scope includes.

Also as @René suggests you can try to put your common templates into some role and declare it as dependency or call `include_role`. As far as I remember while digging the issue, Ansible adds all roles used in current context into search path.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is to put the reusable template in a dependent role. See role [dependencies](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/playbooks_reuse_roles.html#role-dependencies).